# Python list help q = { 1: [[1]] }

Tags: python

can someone please explain to me what this line does ?

```
q = { 1: [[1]] }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

It creates a dictionary with one key, whose value is a nested list:

```
>>> q = { 1: [[1]] } 
>>> q.keys()
[1]
>>> q[1]
[[1]]
>>> q[1][0]
[1]
>>> q[1][0][0]
1
```

Remember that in python, lists use 0-based indexing, so the `[0]` references in the above example retrieve the *first* element of the list.

Or to approach it from the other side:

- `1` is just a literal integer value
- `[elem1, elem2, elem3]` is a list definition, so `[1]` is a list with *one* element in it, the integer `1`.
- `{key: value}` is a dictionary definition, connecting a set of keys with corresponding values. `{1: 1}` creates a dictionary with 1 key-value pair, a key of `1` pointing to a value of `1`.
- Lists and dictionaries can be nested; lists can be dictionary values, and you can also put lists inside other lists.

  - `[[]]` is a list with 1 element, another, empty list.
  - `[[1]]` is a list with 1 element, another list, which has 1 element too, the integer value 1.
  - `{1: [[1]]}` is a dictionary with one key, the integer value 1, which is connected to a list with one element, another list that again has only 1 element, another integer value 1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but could you please explain to me how can this help me ? I mean can you give me an another example please ?

Comment: @SerjCodito: Expanded again. You *really* want to go read a good tutorial; lists for [programmers](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers) and [non-programmers](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers) are both available.

Answer (score 1):

We create a dictionary with a single element

whose key an integer 1

and the value is a list with a single element

the element is another list

with another single element

which is an integer 1